# Configuring Google Annotated Timeline

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, google-visualization

I have a working Google Annotated Timeline (see docs at http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/annotatedtimeline.html).

I would like to explicitly set a start_date and end_date, I presume by using `zoomStartTime` and `zoomEndTime`. But, I cannot get it to work and I think it's either because my syntax is wrong or because I'm using the wrong format for dates.

My last line of the function:

```
chart.draw(data, {'displayAnnotations': true}, {'zoomStartTime': new Date(2011, 6, 26)}, {'zoomEndTime': new Date(2011,6,30)});
```

How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should merge the options in a single hash:

```
chart.draw(data, {'displayAnnotations': true,
                  'zoomStartTime': new Date(2011, 6, 26),
                  'zoomEndTime': new Date(2011,6,30)
                  }
           );
```