# gvisAnnotationChart and zoomStartTime / zoomEndTime

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis, annotatedtimeline

I'm having some trouble with the zoomStartTime and zoomEndTime parameters of gvisAnnotationChart from the googleVis package.

Specifically, running example three:

```
A3 <- gvisAnnotationChart(Stock, datevar="Date",
                           numvar="Value", idvar="Device",
                           titlevar="Title", annotationvar="Annotation",
                           options=list(
                             width=600, height=350,
                            zoomStartTime=as.Date("2008-01-04"),
                            zoomEndTime=as.Date("2008-01-05"))
                          )
plot(A3)
```

Produces a plot with "undefined is not a function" in the y scroll area.

The documentation states "Zoom into the time window, no Y-axis ticks" but has no other information. 
I have seen several examples on JSFiddle of this working, [Configuring Google Annotated Timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6483801/configuring-google-annotated-timeline),
but I can't translate this to R. Any help would be appreciated.